# c# cannot deserialize a nested json string

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize a nested json string

```
   public class recentlySearchedAdd
    {
        public recentlySearchedAdd()
        {
            searchedLocations = new List<recentlySearchedLoc>();
        }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public List<recentlySearchedLoc> searchedLocations { get; set; }
    }

    public class recentlySearchedLoc
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }

    }
```

And here is the code to handle to json string

```
        //dummy json string
        string json = "{\"status\": \"OK\", \"searchedLocations\": [{\"id\": 7, \"location\": \"California\"}, {\"id\": 4, \"location\": \"90007\"}, {\"id\": 3, \"location\": \"New York, NY\"}]}";
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<recentlySearchedAdd> recentlySearchedAddList = ser.Deserialize<List<recentlySearchedAdd>>(json);
        Response.Write("count:"+recentlySearchedAddList.Count);
```

The count is 0...what's wrong with this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. What serializer returns is `recentlySearchedAdd` not a list of it.

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
recentlySearchedAdd recentlySearchedAddList = ser.Deserialize<recentlySearchedAdd>(json);
Console.Write("count:" + recentlySearchedAddList.searchedLocations.Count);
```